# Как перевернуть все нечётные слова во введённой строке?

Tags: python, алгоритм, строки

Как ввести с клавиатуры текст и перевернуть все нечетные слова?

Единственное, до чего пока додумался:

```
s = input('Введите текст: ')
print(s[::-1])
```

Comment: Единственное до чего я додумался.

s=input('Введите текст: ')
print(s[::-1])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разбиваем строку на слова, затем обходим все элементы функцией `map`, первым аргументом передаем лямбда-функцию, в которой делаем реверс нечетных слов, вторым аргументом - счетчик, а третьим - список слов. Затем восстанавливаем строку:

```
input_str = input()
words = input_str.split(' ')
res = map(lambda i, w: w[::-1] if i % 2 != 0 else w, range(len(words)), words)
print(' '.join(res))
```

Можно без `map`, а с помощью спискового включения, тогда не придется брать длину, а воспользоваться функцией `enumerate`:

```
res = [w[::-1] if i % 2 != 0 else w for i, w in enumerate(words)]
```

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо. :)

Answer (score 4):

я бы сделал это следующим образом:

```
In [1]: words = input().split()
123 456 789

In [2]: words
Out[2]: ['123', '456', '789']

In [3]: words[::2] = [w[::-1] for w in words[::2]]

In [4]: words
Out[4]: ['321', '456', '987']
```

PS [почему генератор предпочтительнее `map()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)